# focus to a DOM element doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, marionette

I have this function on a Marionette view

```
onShow: function(){
            // $('#boxId').val("I am here");
            $('#boxId').focus();

        }
```

When I use the `$('#boxId').val("I am here");` it works well and the element's value is `I am here`. But when I try to focus on that element, it doesn't work, it doesn't focus. Any idea what is the problem?

I also tried

```
<input type="text" class="input_txt" id="boxId" maxlength="8" onload="$('#boxId').focus()">
```

and

```
onShow: function(){;
             $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('#boxId').focus();

                });
        }
```

but it also didn't work.

Finally solved with:

```
onShow: function(){
              setTimeout(function(){
                        $('#boxId').focus();
                    },1000);
        },
```

Comment: Can you please create a JSFiddle, which illustrates the problem?

Comment: `label` doesn't fire `onload` event.

Comment: @Teemu you are right, my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm in agreement that setTimeout is not the best solution and also and indication that you are trying to access the element before it exists.

I've found that the `onShow` method can behave strangely if you are working with deeply nested layouts and views. What can happen is that if at any point in the hierarchy you call `.show()` in `onRender` of a layout then every subview of that layout will respond immediately to the "show" triggered by that particular `show()`. This means these views' `onShow()` methods can be invoked well before their DOM subtrees are ready or inserted in the DOM.

If you're doing a lot of deeply nested views, I'd check through carefully and make sure that you are only calling `.show()` in your layouts' `onShow` method.

Comment: Addendum: If you're using Marionette 1.8 you can use [onDomRefresh](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.view.md#view-domrefresh--ondomrefresh-event) to assure yourself that the DOM has been truly updated before trying to use jQuery.

Comment: I've had instances where even with the element in question being present in the DOM, focus() wouldn't work, but the `autofocus` attribute did.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead: `$('#boxId')[0].focus()`

Comment: $(...).focus() is for attaching an onfocus handler, not for setting the focus on element

Comment: It will trigger with no arguments

Comment: If $('#anything'); returns more than one element, then there are deeper issues at hand :) -- having non-unique IDs

Comment: @kmatheny, a simpler way to abuse your computer is just by slamming it with a hammer :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious is it valid to focus a label? Try focusing the input instead?
Are you calling focus at the correct time? Have you tried doing it in a document on ready or settimeout or body onload

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#myBox').focus();
});

  setTimeout(function(){
    $('#myBox').focus();
  },1000);

 <body onload="$('#myBox').focus();">
```

http://api.jquery.com/focus/

--Note the document on ready goes in the page randomly and runs on page load

```
<input type="text" id="selectMe"/>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#selectMe').focus();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Glad to hear, setTimeout will work but its not the best solution it is suggesting that the element doesn't exist or isn't selectable at the time that you are applying the focus, ideally you would set the focus when the element is focusable or exists

Answer (score 0):

If you use `setTimeout` then I would guess that you're calling  `$('#boxId').focus();` before the element is available -- your `<script>` is above your `<input>`.

You should be placing your `<script>` tags just before the closing body tag `</body>` in almost every circumstance. There are lots of reasons for this, and preventing this type of issue is one of them.